# When we derive the distribution of a product of variables, how do we justify the absolute value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So in [the derivation of the pdf of a product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) $\int_R f_X (x) f_Y(\frac{z}{x}) |\frac{1}{x}|dx$, I understand conceptually that pdfs need to be non-negative, and I understand that the absolute value is ensuring that, but this justification feels a little bit post-hoc to me.

I'm confused about where our ordinary rules of differentiation break down in going from $F_Z (z)$ to its derivative. The wikipedia derivation (linked above) seems to arbitrarily partition the domains into positive and negative parts to make the absolute value sort of fall out (and again, I understand we need the absolute value to ensure non-negativity of $p_Z (z)$), but is there a more natural way to justify it?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure to really understand your question but the absolute value arise from the fact that when $x<0$, then $-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{|x|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they partition the domain is in line $4$ of the derivation. They want to isolate $Y$, so they divide by $X$. They must split it into two cases here, because the inequality flips if $X$ is negative:
$$
P(XY\le z)
= P\left(Y\le \frac zX \wedge X>0\right) + P\left(Y\ge \frac zX \wedge X<0\right).
$$
So they really have no choice. Later they introduce the absolute value just to simplify the final result (they write $-1/x=1/|x|$ for $x\le 0$), but the maths has already happened as this point. It's really just to make the formula prettier/nicer.

Comment: should be rather $P(...\wedge X>0)+P(...\wedge X<0)$

Comment: @Surb Oh, to avoid dividing by $0$ (and to make a prpoer partition I guess)? I guess, but it's pretty common to just ignore undefined values on a null-set, right?